# using multiple modelAttributes to receive 2 objects from JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which there are 2 parts. It is basically a note taking application with 2 modes, one is groupMode and other is personalMode. Now they both have their different dao's, serviceImpl in the backend, but they are in one controller view.

I have a boolean value to set, to know which mode is the user currently in, to perform CRUD operations in the specific database table. Now As both group modes are personal modes are in the same view, I have to make my methods so they can accept objects from either of the mode. Does spring support accepting only one object even if I declare 2 in model attribute. Here is the example of what I want to achieve :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/section/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    boolean addSection(@ModelAttribute("section") Section section, @ModelAttribute("groupsection") GroupSection groupSection,Model model) {
       if(boolean == true){
       this.groupSectionService.addGroupSection(groupSection);
       model.addAttribute("groupsection", new GroupSection());
     } else{
       this.sectionService.addSection(section);
        model.addAttribute("section", new Section());
       }
        return true;
    }
```

Is this possible, I will always be sending one object from the front-end. Thanks a lot. Any pointers or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Note : I would like to do same way for edit, delete for section.

Comment: and when you try it, what happens? does it work? however in worst case, you can always wrap two models into one by composition.

Comment: That is the problem, I have tried a crude version of it, which seems to be working. I will require to change a lot. Composition, never heard of it, I will google it, but if you some proper name for it, lemme know. Thanks.

Comment: by composition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) I meant that if you have a problem with two model, you can create special one with can hold both sub-models. but maybe you can work it out somehow also with two models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is such a `if`-statement that "split" the complete controller method, like yours, I have the feeling that one controller method should been replaced by two methods, one for each case.

The easiest, and most straight forward solution would been using two different URLs.

But maybe you have some reason for using the same URL, then I would have two different controller methods with the same URL but a different `params` Attribute in `@RequestMapping`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/section/add",
                method = RequestMethod.POST
                params="createGroupSection=false")
@ResponseBody
public boolean addSection(@ModelAttribute("section") Section section) {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "/section/add",
                method = RequestMethod.POST
                params="createGroupSection=true")
@ResponseBody
public boolean addGroupSection(@ModelAttribute("section") Section section) {...}
```

Comment: I think I will use the params method... Thanks a lot.. :-)